Wso2 APIM Web Socket API context
We are using WSO2 API Manager version 4.0.0 to expose a SignalR service implemented in .NET Core. The frontend is built with Angular.
Here is how we have configured the APIs.
WebSocket API:
WSO2 Endpoint: wss://localhost:8099/chathub/1.0.0/chathub
Backend Endpoint: wss://localhost:30002/chathub
Topic: The WebSocket API is configured to handle messages related to the chathub topic.
REST API:
WSO2 Endpoint: https://localhost:8243/chats/1.0.0/chathub
Purpose: This REST API provides functionalities such as generating a connection ID and other necessary responses required by the client to initiate and maintain a WebSocket connection with the SignalR service.
Can we add same context in two API's in wso2 apim in which one is REst api and other is Web Socket? Or can we change the Web Socket port to https port 8243? Is there any possibility that two api have same context like /chathub?
One more thing can we change in SignalR that if hits at https://localhost:8243/chats/1.0.0/chathub first get all response and then connect wss://localhost:8099/chathub/1.0.0/chathub at websocket on this Url? If yes what is the possile solution.

The API Manager currently handles the two transports: web socket and HTTP separately. Web sockets are deployed using an inbound endpoint that is exposed using port 9099 for WS and 8099 for WSS. Therefore these two types of APIs cannot be exposed using the same port.
Also, yes. It is not allowed to create two APIs with the same context in the publisher portal.
Suggested Solution:
Having a deployment before the API Gateway will help you in this case to properly manage the routing so that if there is an web-socket Upgrade header in the request, it will be routed to the web socket API and if there is no Upgrade header, it will be routed to the REST API.

I have done this back. By making the backend run on WSS and then adding the URL mapping in wso2 APIM API that works for us and it also works through HTTP.
